# The sort functions are not working as I intended in Thonny Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I used the following code in my program, with the intention of the highest mark being at the top and the lowest being at the bottom, but when it runs, any number with 2 or more digits doesn't function properly. Please Help, Thanks. Dont know what else to write but it makes me write something.

```
print("**********STUDENT ANALYSIS**********")
people = []
score = []
people.append("Doc")
people.append("Sarah")
people.append("Jar-Jar")
people.append("Jake")
people.append("Ben")
people.append("BB8")
people.append("R2D2")
people.append("Gollum")
people.append("Frodo")
people.append("Snoke")
Doc1 = input("Enter the test score for Doc ")
print("Test score:", Doc1)
Sarah1 = input("Enter the test score for Sarah ")
print("Test score:", Sarah1)
Jar1 = input("Enter the test score for Jar-Jar ")
print("Test score:", Jar1)
Jake1 = input("Enter the test score for Jake ")
print("Test score:", Jake1)
Ben1 = input("Enter the test score for Ben ")
print("Test score:", Ben1)
BB8 = input("Enter the test score for BB8 ")
print("Test score:", BB8)
R2D2 = input("Enter the test score for R2D2 ")
print("Test score:", R2D2)
Gollum1 = input("Enter the test score for Gollum ")
print("Test score:", Gollum1)
Frodo1 = input("Enter the test score for Frodo ")
print("Test score:", Frodo1)
Snoke1 = input("Enter the test score for Snoke ")
print("Test score:", Snoke1)





print("STUDENT MARKS") 
score.append(Doc1)
score.append(Sarah1)
score.append(Jar1)
score.append(Jake1)
score.append(Ben1)
score.append(BB8)
score.append(R2D2)
score.append(Gollum1)
score.append(Frodo1)
score.append(Snoke1)




sort = sorted(score, reverse = True)


print("[",sort[0],", '", people[0],"']")
print("[",sort[1],", '", people[1],"']")
print("[",sort[2],", '", people[2],"']")
print("[",sort[3],", '", people[3],"']")
print("[",sort[4],", '", people[4],"']")
print("[",sort[5],", '", people[5],"']")
print("[",sort[6],", '", people[6],"']")
print("[",sort[7],", '", people[7],"']")
print("[",sort[8],", '", people[8],"']")
print("[",sort[9],", '", people[9],"']")
```

Comment: `input()` receives user input and store it as a string. If you expect to use this input as a number, you should use `int()` or `float()` to change its type.

Comment: Preparing a good [mcve] is a useful task. For example, eliminate the `input()`, unless that is somehow essential. Also, reduce it to just the required number of elements. I'd expect two elements to be enough, any smaller sequence is always sorted anyway.

Comment: Strings don't sort the same as numbers.  `Aardvark` comes before `Bug` in the dictionary, but `11111111` is larger than `222`.

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

1. There is an awful lot of repeated code, which breaks the DRY rule (don't repeat yourself). You can remove/simplify it using loops/comprehension (see below)
2. You are using two parallel lists to store data. This may lead to problems if the lists lose synchronization; I would suggest a dictionary.
3. The only issue with a dictionary is that it is not sorted. See code below for a way around this.

## Here is a (shortened) list of students

people = ['Doc1', 'Sarah1', 'Jar1']

## create an empty dictionary

mark_dictionary = {}

## and populate with the names of students and their marks

## note that keys are str, marks are int

for name in people:
# prompt the user with the student's name
mark = int(input('Enter the mark for {}: '.format(name)))
mark_dict[name] = mark

## print the dictionary entries sorted on the value in reverse (descending) order

print([(key, value) for (key, value) in sorted(mark_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)])

...and you're done